# checking if value is null using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if the value of my variable is null but it does not work. And i also have to stop script and don't insert the row

**Html**

```
<input type="text" name="for_intitule" id="form_intitule">
```

**Jquery**

```
var form_intitule = $('input[name=form_intitule]').val();

if(form_intitule == null){
  alert('fill the blank');
  return false;
}
```

**UPDATE :**

```
$('#insertForm').on('click', function(){
  var form_intitule = $('input[name=form_intitule]').val();

  if($('input[name=form_intitule]').val().trim().length == 0){
    alert('fill the blank');
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "lib/function.php?insertForm="+insertForm+"&form_intitule="+form_intitule,
    dataType : "html",
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
    },
    success:function(data){
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your browser at the `if` statement line, what is the value of `form_intitule` when the input box is blank?

Comment: it will be empty, not `null` or `undefined`

Comment: The `.val()` always returns a string. You can check if the string is empty using: `.val().trim().length == 0`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's kinda puzzling that you closed this as a duplicate of unrelated question and then give a completely different answer

Comment: @Juhana That was in the duplicates list.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yeah well perhaps it's better to use your own judgement instead of blindly closing questions because there happens to be something in a list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) always returns a `string`. You can check if the string is empty using:

```
.val().trim().length == 0
```

So your full condition will be:

```
var form_intitule = $('input[name=form_intitule]').val().trim();

if (form_intitule.length == 0) {
  alert('fill the blank');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: tank you, it's working but my value is inserted ..

Comment: @LucasFrugier Put it in the `submit` event while you `return false`. Can you show the full code? Thanks.

Comment: my post is updated :)

Comment: @LucasFrugier You forgot to add the `return false` after the alert. Oops.

Comment: oh :o 
my bad ! thank you

Comment: @LucasFrugier Ha ha... $h!t happens! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a safer method

```
var formElement = $('input[name=form_intitule]');
if ($(formElement).length == 0 || $(formElement).val().trim().length == 0) {
   console.log("element does not exist OR value is empty");
}
```